# how to change the url without changing the folder?

Tags: php, url-routing, smarty

I am using MVC framework in my website.In my webpage URL file extension is not showing.I need to specify the file extension like

```
www.legacy.com/women/tops.php
```

but its showing only

```
www.legacy.com/women/tops/
```

for seo purpose I want to change the url with extension. But I can't change the folder or file name.

One more doubt I have that.My webpage is showing

```
www.legacy.com/women/tops/
```

like this I want to change this as www.legacy.com/women_tops.php/
Is it possible?

Thank you

Here is the code I use to associate a URL with a controller:

```
$arrCommands = array (
    'home' => "contents",
    'members' => "",        
);

if ( $arrCommands[$command1] == "*" )
{
    $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/" . $command1 . "/" . $command2 . ".php";

    if ( !file_exists($includeFile) )
        $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/" . $command1 . "/default.php";
}
    elseif ( !array_key_exists($command1, $arrCommands) )
    {
        $includeFile    =   CONTROLLER_PATH . "/contents/" . $command1 . ".php";
        if ( !file_exists($includeFile))
    Header( "Location: http://metroplots.ragedev/404_error/" );     
    }
else
{
    $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/". $arrCommands[$command1] . "/" . $command1 . ".php";

    if ( !file_exists($includeFile) )
        $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/contents/home.php";
}

include_once($includeFile);
```

Comment: Depend on the MVC you use... In [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) we can define the extension

Comment: without changing any MVC structure I want to change the URL Is it possible

Comment: No i'm not asking you to change the MVC.. Btw,what framework do u use?

Comment: PHP+Smarty = .htaccess is your only option. You are not using any Framework... simply php with template engine.

Comment: But my model structure MVC framework

Comment: can you please clarify what MVC framework you use? MVC should have ONLY 1 entry point though some bootstrap and then route to controller... If you have "custom mvc" you can create custom plugin to change rewrite controller/action at runtime.

Comment: controller_action.php file is there all pages are going to this page first and then redirecting to other pages.Here only i added the 404 error page redirection

Comment: what is written in your .htaccess file, it must have written rule for removing file extension,

Comment: #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php [R=301,L] in my file .htaccess have this two lines

Comment: these rules are commented, find .htaccess file in your root folder and show what are the rules, root folder is a folder where your actual index.php file is

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller [L]

<Files controller>
 ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

Comment: rename this file and check you may able to access your files with extension

Comment: Post the code you are using to parse the URL.

Comment: Smarty? Where is your existing template code?

Comment: <?
$arrCommands = array
     (
      'home'     => "contents",
      'members'    => "*",
      'coimbatore'   => "*",     
           
     );  
if ( $arrCommands[$command1] == "*" )
{
 
 $includeFile  = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/" . $command1 . "/" . $command2 . ".php";
 if ( !file_exists($includeFile) )
  $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/" . $command1 . "/default.php";
}
else
{
 $includeFile  = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/". $arrCommands[$command1] . "/" . $command1 . ".php";
 if ( !file_exists($includeFile) )
  $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH . "/contents/home.php";
}include_once($includeFile);
?>

Comment: here i am directing the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the technology your looking for is called **url rewriting**

the idea is taking a give url and rewriting it on the server side. lots of software use this method to not expose logic via get parameters...

e.g.
http://domain.com/blog/2

according to the server, this url is actually:

http://domain.com/index.php?cat=blog&page=2

on linux/apache servers is is achieved via modrewrite:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

using .htaccess files on the server that explain the rewrite rules and route urls.

microsoft iis servers have their own flavor (and syntax) called url rewrite:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

there are some tools out there to do this for you (here's an overview of 6 of them)
http://webm.ag/2009/12/15/6-of-the-best-mod-rewrite-generators/

but i feel like most times your best best is to manually create your own.

here's an example of the one i use on my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

basically this ruleset will redirect all traffic to index.php

in my MVC i have a generic controller called "url_logic" that runs first and looks at what the url is. and based upon it's logic it creates the necessary controllers to create the site (even if it's a 404 error controller).

hope that helps get you started!

also, if your using windows .htaccess files are tough to work with. i suggest naming them
htaccess.txt and when you upload them to the server rename them there.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand this and I performed this.But i have a problem in index.php file. from .htaccess file i am redirecting to index.php in this file i am taking the url www.legacy.com/women_tops.php and performing one condition if it is true i want to redirect to www.legacy.com/women/tops/  page.When i give Header( "Location: legacy.com/women/tops "); then the url will again change.I think you understand my problem

Comment: In .htaccess i tried this also RewriteRule ^womens-tops.php?$ womens/tops/ for me its not working here womens is a folder tops is a php file

Answer (score 5):

.htaccess can do magic. Can rewrite anything to whatever you want, can get messy...
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

You should also be able to do this in the application itself. In most good frameworks you can use customize routes, [here is zend example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: without changing server and MVC by using smarty can i do this

Comment: no. smarty is simply template engine. It has to be framework specific re-routing plugin (if your framework supports routing ofcourse)

Comment: framework is Zend/Codeigniter/Cake/etc... php with smarty is plain PHP.

Comment: Oh i thought smarty is also framework So i am using plain php

Comment: question: is every page of your site a separate entry point or is it all going to controller/actions through 1 main file?

Comment: its going to controller action

Comment: Can you post your controller code (or at least the bit that does the loading of the page requested) so we can assist you with implementing some routing?

Comment: i added the controller action above

Answer (score 1):

You have to add below 2 line in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^women/tops /women_tops.php
```

Comment: i can't open htaccess   its asking some key

Comment: open the .htaccess with notepad (or whatever plain text editor)

Comment: What key is it asking? Are you using ssh?

Answer (score 1):

create a index.php file, which will be read as default file for display and redirect it to your file.

Comment: Header("Location: http://www.legacy.com/womens/top/");   you are telling like this right.if I give redirection the URL will change I want to perform internal redirection

Comment: It depend, the index.php could be able to handle parameter and load the appropriate MVC module depending on this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is mod_rewrite
mod_rewrite:

HIDING EXTENSION IN URL:

mod_rewrite Rewrite Rule generator will take a dynamic url given to it, and generate the correct syntax to place in a .htaccess file to allow the url to be rewritten in a spiderable format. The apache module mod_rewrite converts urls in a certain format to another format, and can be very useful in helping a site with dynamic content to be indexed.

**NOTE** : Before mod_rewrite put in action you should enable it in apache server.

```
Syntax: RewriteRule url-pattern url-new [[flag,...]]
Example: RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R,L]
```

Some useful links-

URL : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

URL : http://tomclegg.net/rewriterule

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^womens_tops.php?$ women/tops [R,L] i tryed this but its not working I think its a problem with controller.php file.In this file i am checking if the file not exist want to redirect to 404 error page ie why its going to error page what I can do

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/rewrite/) web page. i think it may have answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for every one who replayed to this question.

```
$xepWords = explode('_',$command1);
    if($xepWords[0] == 'women')
    {
        $includeFile = CONTROLLER_PATH .'/women/tops.php';
    }
```

I added this code in controller action Now its working fine